# How to set the Start/Load Form with a Button

Tags: c#, winforms

So I'm trying to set the start/load Form in `Program.cs` by a Button.

In the `Program.cs` it states:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Login());
}
```

I need to change Login to Main with the click of a Button.

Comment: How is this question related to C++, if you tagged it, with it?

Comment: Possibly, post the code related to the Button. It's not clear if you want the Login Form to be the starting Form or not.

Comment: I think we're missing some details about this magic button.

Comment: This is really obscure, If you need the form to display a button prior to any other forms starting, theres a few options but i would go either MessageBox (as a function in Main.cs) or design your own form in place of "Login"
I feel more info is needed here

Comment: You need to be a little bit more clear when you are asking any question. but according to what I understand from your statement. You can create a form with just a message and a button and use that form name inside Application.Run(), so that your application will show that message form first. then you can do anything on that button click like showing your main/login form. If this is not what you want then Please give some more idea of your problem. These guys here are really trying to help other programmers.

Comment: When the application runs it starts with `Login` form which is initiated from `program.cs` and in `Login` form `Button_click` event you should code to start the `Main` form. Why would you want to change in `Program.cs`.